# Reading Files from Network Drives in Perl

Tags: perl, networking, drive, file-find

I am working on a perl script which does a document inventory for pdfs in all directories starting from some root directory on our network.  The script runs fine locally, but I can't get it to read files from the network drive.  i have strawberryperl

this is the beginning of my code

```
use strict;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Cwd;
use Tk;
use File::Find;

my @analystreports;
my @directories;
```

I used the Tk Gui to get a directory

```
my $homeDir  = Tk::MainWindow->new->chooseDirectory;
```

capture all files and folders in current directory

```
find(\&grabPDF, $homeDir);

sub grabPDF {

    my $file = $_;
    if ($file =~ /\.pdf/g) {

        push @analystreports, $File::Find::name;
    }
}
```

my network drive looks like this in net use

Local N: Remote \abc-file-01\shared data

Please excuse my beginner code.  My question is whether I'm doing something wrong with a network drive or if I have to ask our administrator for privileges.  Thanks a ton, Dan

Comment: When you say you can't get it to read files, what does that mean?  Do you get an error message?  If so, what is the error message?  I also don't understand what you mean by "my network drive looks like this..."  Could you clarify?  Do you have your network drive mapped to a local drive letter?

Comment: Sure, the network drive is mapped to the letter n.  also the program just runs endlessly. no error message. i appreciate your help

Comment: Endlessly, or for a very long time? You're scanning an entire drive from what you said. That can take a while!

Comment: it is endless.  the time it takes makes no sense.  i'm just looking in one folder.  i have the same folder on my local and it works in half a second

Comment: Does that folder have any folders or symlinks? You are searching recursively. Why don't you add `warn($_)` to your callback sub to track its progress? What does `chooseDirectory` return?

Comment: it has no folders contained, only a bunch of pdf's.  i'll add warn.  choose directory just returns a path like C:/Users/User/Desktop/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drive is a drive. You can either pass any of the following strings:

```
N:\
n:\
N:/
n:/
```

You could even pass the UNC name.

```
\\abc-file-01\shared data
//abc-file-01/shared data
```

Of course, you might have to use some escaping to build the string.

```
"N:\\"
"N:/"
"n:\\"
"n:/"
"\\\\abc-file-01\\shared data"
"//abc-file-01/shared data"
```

But that's probably not relevant since you appear to be getting the string from Tk rather than building it.

There's a bug in your code.

```
if ($file =~ /\.pdf/g) {
```

should be

```
if ($file =~ /\.pdf/) {
```

and probably

```
if ($file =~ /\.pdf\z/) {
```

The `g` makes no sense there and can cause problems (although I think your specific code doesn't suffer). Get rid of the `g`.

Comment: thanks for the help.  why do you think it needs escaping for this drive and not the local?  I have tried all of the other combinations.  thanks for the advice on the g.

Comment: i mean that they way i have it coded works when i pick any folder on my hard drive.  just not on the network drive.  i don't get why i'd have to change the way the path is formatted if that is the case.

Comment: You don't. The paths should not be changed at all.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  you were right to have me add warn($_) it just took a really long time on the network!